# what's wrong in this for loop?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

```
int i, k, j;
    for(j=0; j<5; j++)
    for(i=0,k=0; i<5,k<5; i++,k++)
        System.out.print(c[i]+" : "+p[i][j][k]);
```

I got compiler error for this statement

```
for(i=0,k=0; i<5,k<5; i++,k++)
```

what is wrong here?

Comment: Error is here: `i<5,k<5`: this is not a boolean expression. Maybe you meant `i<5 && k<5`?

Answer (score 2):

In java for loop the condition should give be a `boolean` value so you should use 
either

```
for(i=0,k=0; i<5&&k<5; i++,k++)
```

or

```
for(i=0,k=0; i<5||k<5; i++,k++)
```

Comment: can you see that `i` and `k` have the same values? You can easily drop, say, `k` from the loop

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
for(i=0,k=0; i<5&&k<5; i++,k++)
```

OR

```
for(i=0,k=0; i<5||k<5; i++,k++)
```

instead of

```
for(i=0,k=0; i<5,k<5; i++,k++)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change it to the following to have a boolean expression for the loop:

```
for(i=0,k=0; i<5 && k<5; i++,k++)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the both condition then just try the `||` or `&&` so that it can run....

```
for(i=0,k=0; i<5||k<5; i++,k++)
for(i=0,k=0; i<5&&k<5; i++,k++)
```

---

```
int i, k, j;
for(j=0; j<5; j++)
    for(i=0,k=0; i<5||k<5; i++,k++)
        System.out.print(c[i]+" : "+p[i][j][k]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why on Earth do you loop on two *indistiguishable* `int`s `i` and `k`? 
according your code `k` is just as synonym of `i` and can be easily removed. Do it simply as

```
  for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      System.out.print(c[i] + " : " + p[i][j][i]); // "k" is "i"
```

Answer (score 0):

As said before, the condition must be a single one.

If you want it to run while at least one of the two is under the given value use:

```
i<5 || k<5
```

If you want it to run untill one of the two surpasses the given value use:

```
i<5 && k<5
```